# JasperReports Server with Oracle and WebSphere

Tags: oracle10g, jasper-reports, websphere, jasperserver

Is it possible to deploy *JasperReport Server 4.7.0* community project on *WebSphere* application server and create the JR repository in *Oracle 10g* instead of *MySQL*?

If it is possible then what are the required possible configurations needed, as community edition does not provide official support for these servers.